# How can I dynamically change sqlalchemy __tablename__ at run time for purpose of localization using fastapi?

Tags: dynamic, sqlalchemy, localization, fastapi, tablename

I am building a multilingual api for an educational app using fastapi.
I have created differrent tables for translated parts and created mysql views for differrent languages.
I did not want to write differrent pydantic classes for each translated table parts.

Instead I wrote sone functions to manipulate sqlalchemy _*tablename*_ attribute of sqlachemy tables. This way I thought I could reach differrent tables like lessons_en or lessons_de which are just mysql views for translated parts. Table structure and view structure matches the original sqlalchemy model and pydantic schema.

e.g.

```py
def get_table_suffix():
    lang = sys_vars.CURRENT_LOCAL__LANG
    print(str(lang) + "from get_table_suffix")
    match lang:
        case "":
            return ""
        case "en":
            return "_en"
        case "de":
            return "_de"


def get_localized_table_name(tbl_nm: str):
    table_name = tbl_nm + get_table_suffix()
    return table_name
```

then..

```py
class LessonSummary(Base):
    __tablename__ = get_localized_table_name("lessons")
```

for matching correct language view
then at login function I call ..

```py
    settings: dict = get_user_settings(user)
    set_user_lang(settings)
    sys_vars.CURRENT_LOCAL__LANG = sys_vars.LOCAL_LANGUAGES[settings["language"]]
```

these functions set CURRENT_LOCAL__LANG which happens ( I tested it )
But since the tables are loaded, changing tablename does not change tables.

```py
def get_user_settings(user: schemas.User):
    settings: dict = {}
    for setting in user.Settings:
        settings[setting.SettingName] = setting.SettingValue
    return settings


def set_user_lang(settings: dict):
    sys_vars.CURRENT_LOCAL__LANG = sys_vars.LOCAL_LANGUAGES[settings["language"]]
    print(sys_vars.CURRENT_LOCAL__LANG + " from set_user_lang")
    return sys_vars.CURRENT_LOCAL__LANG
```

However, _*tablename*_ attribute is set at loading time and I cannot seem to change it at run time.
I tried to do it before the app loaded routers but user login happens after app startup and I need to reach the instance of the table. I tried MetaData() obj but no-luck

So, my question..
Am I going the wrong way about this problem?
Can I dynamically change the _*tablename*_ at run time and reflect the changes in session.
Do I need a reload somehow?
I did manage to store language correctly inside jwt but I can't change the tablename.
So How can I change it at runtime?

I tried changing the tablename dynamically but sine the app had already loaded I was not successful.

Comment: If they are just views - do you really need to invoke the ORM mapping for those queries? Would a plain query / select statement work better?

Comment: The views are select statements on mysql side but if I don't use orm mapping, Then I would need to write many crud functions to create, update, delete functions. If I could reach the table instance and change the tablename and refresh session after login, it would be cleanest since translated table structure matches original pydantic models

Comment: I realized that my first answer was useless and deleted it. Sorry for taking your time. I posted another answer. I hope this time it will be helpful for you.

Comment: I'll check it out later today and report back. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question since I don't think there is an answer to my original question which was dynamically changing sqlalchemy tables pointing at differrent tables or views depending on user's local language without duplicating a lot code.

My database design was right for future exandibility.

I had a table for translation languages and a lessons_translation table

```
lessons
-------
id
title
description
body

lessons_trs
----------
id
lesson_id
language_id
title
description
body
```

I also had a view with join of lessons and lessons_trs.
let's say for german selected view

```sql
select lessons.id, lessons_trs.title, lessons_trs.description, lessons_trs.body 
from lessons_trs, lessons
where lessons_trs.language_id="de" 
and lessons_trs.lesson_id=lessons.id
```

and the view with select statement above was called lessons_de.
This gives me a translated table view like..

```
lessons_de
----------
id
title
description
body
```

..which matches pydantic schemas since lessons and lessons_de data structure match exactly.

It would be as simple as changing sqlalchemy _*tablename*_ and refreshing the session to point to another table at runtime.

Even though Yurii's solution is a working one, it requires me to duplicate data classes as many as translated language.

So I ended up creating new Tables inside sqlalchemy models and adding a language checking if statement for all my crud functions. It's still better than adding matching pydantic classes for each translation.

I am a bit disappointed since I was expecting better localization options from sqlalchemy and fastapi.

May be they have a mechanism for it and I could not find it yet but I have to go on since I've already spent a few days on this subject.

I wanted to leave the answer here for possible future solutions or updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use imperative mapping style instead of declarative style. With imperative style your model classes are not linked to metadata until you link them by calling `mapper_registry.map_imperatively()`.

But in this case there are some duplication (you have to declare fields twice - in model and in table).

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

from sqlalchemy.orm import registry, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String

mapper_registry = registry()
metadata = MetaData()

user_lang: str = ''

@dataclass
class LessonSummary:
    id: int = field(init=False)
    title: str


def get_localized_table_name(tb_name):
    return f"{tb_name}_{user_lang}"


def create_localized_tables(engine):
    localized_table_name = get_localized_table_name("lessons")

    lesson_summary_table = Table(
        localized_table_name,
        mapper_registry.metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('title', String(50))
    )

    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(LessonSummary, lesson_summary_table)

    mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)

user_lang = input("Language:")

# When you have all necessary data, create tables
create_localized_tables(engine)

# And you can use your models
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

with session_maker() as session:

    l1 = LessonSummary("Lesson 1")

    session.add(l1)
    session.commit()

    lesson = session.get(LessonSummary, 1)
    print(lesson.title)
```

Output:

```
CREATE TABLE lessons_me (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        title VARCHAR(50), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO lessons_me (title) VALUES (?)
('Lesson 1',)

FROM lessons_me 
WHERE lessons_me.id = ?
(1,)

Lesson 1
```